# Applying different CSS style for each element in For Loop - Django

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm building a blog with Django and i'm trying to apply my static design to dynamic HTML templates. I have several CSS classes for diffrenet card types (regular, medium and large), and i'm builing a posts page that should display all posts from all classes.

I'm trying to find a solution for looping through every post and applying different CSS class accordingly.

To sum it up:

1. i have a posts list in my db
2. i want to loop over all the posts and assign different pre-defined CSS class to different posts (meaning the "class" should be different for some posts, some should have class "card" and some "large-card", etc)

Any help?

Here is a sample of the html code i refer to:

```
    {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="card">
...
</div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various possibilities to do that:

1. How about just using a the [built-in forloop variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) (scroll down a bit for a list of availabel variables):

   ```
   {% for post in post_list %}
       <div class="card{{ forloop.counter }}"> {{ post }} </div>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. You could also make `post_list` a list of tuples in the backend, i.e. something like `post_list = [ ("a", "class_a"), ("b", "class_b")]`. Then in the template you can unpack this:

   ```
   {% for post in post_list %}
        <div class="card{{ post.1 }}"> {{ post.0 }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
3. There are more, you can use the built-in [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) for example

Comment: Thanks, I was managed so solve this issue using “Slice” and choosing different posts and then assign different classes when looping over the posts in the database

Answer (score 0):

I was managed so solve this issue using “Slice” and choosing different posts and then assign different classes when looping over the posts in the database.